# SQL expression to return rows where delimited strings don't match

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to write a SQL expression in Big Query that will return rows where the stated Column_A language does not match the stated Column_B language. Both columns contain strings.

- The two possible languages are English/EN or French/FR.
- I can't expect a single naming convention, capitalization case and it may appear at the beginning or the end of the string.
- But I can expect a delimiter such as _, -, or ().
- Finally Column A and B may have different formats or delimiters from each other.

So far the best solution I have is to use LIKE for every possible permutation. But there has to be a better way to do this.

Can anyone help me out?

```
SELECT
  Column_A,
  Column_B,
FROM
  `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
WHERE
  (Column_A LIKE "%\\_EN\\_%" AND Column_B LIKE "%FR\\_%")
  OR 
  (Column_A LIKE "%\\_en\\_%" AND Column_B LIKE "%fr\\_%")
  OR 
  (Column_A LIKE "%\\(EN\\)%" AND Column_B LIKE "%\\(FR\\)%")
  [...]
```

Comment: Could you replace all possible delimiters (including spaces) with nothing for both Column_A and Column_B as well as forcing upper or lower case and then compare them?

Comment: can you provide example of your data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

You could use REGEX_CONTAINS

link here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_contains

here's an attempt at the regex you might want

```
where ((REGEX_CONTAINS(upper(Column_A),r"[E][N][A-z ]+[.\\()-\/][E][N]") and not(REGEX_CONTAINS(upper(Column_B),r"[E][N][A-z ]+[.\\()-\/][E][N]")))
    or (REGEX_CONTAINS(upper(Column_A),r"[F][R][A-z ]+[.\\()-\/][F][R]") and not(REGEX_CONTAINS(upper(Column_B),r"[F][R][A-z ]+[.\\()-\/][F][R]"))))
```

here's a good tool for creating and testing your regular expressions: 
https://regexr.com/

you'd have to use this to find any entries that don't fit the regex

```
where ((not(REGEX_CONTAINS(upper(Column_A),r"[E][N][A-z ]+[.\\()-\/][E][N]")) and not(REGEX_CONTAINS(upper(Column_A),r"[E][N][A-z ]+[.\\()-\/][E][N]")))
    or (not(REGEX_CONTAINS(upper(Column_B),r"[F][R][A-z ]+[.\\()-\/][F][R]")) and not(REGEX_CONTAINS(upper(Column_B),r"[F][R][A-z ]+[.\\()-\/][F][R]"))))
```